# How to name HTML Input id name for a input question "I don't have a preference"

Tags: html, input, namespaces, tags, label

My question of the day: I am working on a fake dating website and ask the user what their interested gender is and provide them the option to say they do not have preference. I want a logical and readable id name. I have made interest-none but is there a better option for naming this certain case scenario?

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="interested-gender" id="interest-none" checked>
<label class="form-check-label" for="interest-none">
 I don't have a preference
</label>
```

Comment: no-preference ?

Comment: thank you!!! such a simple answer. genius.

Comment: thanks I didn't wash my brain to find this one, it was already written in your question!:)

Comment: I was just over thinking this morning haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question would probably be closed after being flagged as "opinion-based".

But naming is one of the most difficult things in development and I personally think it's totally fine to ask for a name suggestion from other developers. If StackOverflow is not the right place to ask for other developers' suggestions, what is?

Here are some suggestions from me:

```
no-preference
interest-no-preference
interest-neutral
```

Comment: totally agree with you, number of time I'm stuck with naming (css, variable, function...),... Nice answers by the way